dolphin-emu: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVM-11.so.1
When running the Dolphin emulator from the stable Debian repos in Debian 12 with KDE I get the below error. However, no error is shown on a nearly identical machine where Dolphin emulator works fine. I already tried removing and then reinstalling dolphin-emu but I still get the same error. libllvm13 is the oldest version that is available in the repos. Installing that didn't help. There is no llvm-libs in the repos that's recommended in another question similar to this. It looks like in the machine where it works I have llvm11 installed locally (not from the repos) but llvm is not in the Debian repos. Bug report 1
When I run env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb dolphin-emu it shows:
dolphin-emu: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVM-11.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Update: it does work in Lutris (if the environment variable is configured in the Dolphin settings) so that's a workaround as is compiling Dolphin.
Update: after updating the Dolphin runner in Lutris the Dolphin runner doesn't work anymore either: it shows this in the console: /home/username/.local/share/lutris/runners/dolphin/dolphin-emu: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory and I only have the .59 package. That's probably a bug in Lutris (?). Dolphin can be started when changing the executable to /usr/games/dolphin-emu in the Lutris settings for Dolphin.

Have you tried downloading the library from sid repos?: https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libavformat60/download If installing the package will work, you can manually update till it gets pushed to stable repos :-)

No, I think it could cause problems with incompatabilities. It's also not hashed and I wouldn't know where to put it. However, it may help other people having the same problem. For now, I'm using an old Dolphin build that I had compiled (did run type -a dolphin-emu to see where it is).

What is the version of the emulator?  The minimum supported LLVM in the bookworm repository is LLVM-14 and isn't listed as a dependency of dolphin-emu, and I don't understand why you need libavformat.so.60 when 59 is the dependency.

Why are you trying to run the version of dolphin from the stable repos on testing? dolphin-emu is available in debian testing; this is definitely an issue with forward porting, and not with the package itself.
Just install the normal version of dolphin-emu from the Debian 12 repos, if debian 12 is what you want to be running.

@eyoung100 That error about libavformat.so.60 is shown for the Lutris runner, not the version installed system-wide from the Debian repos. There I (still) have the libLLVM-11.so.1 error.  Calum McConnell no idea why you think I'm running testing. I run stable (D12) and only nearly only things from stable installed (and a few things from backports).

@mYnDstrEAm what incompabilities? You would just need to sudo dpkg -i packagenamehere it and if it didn't work for you, you can always purge/delete it ;-)

Appologies for my confusion; I forgot that Debian 12 is now released, and it is Debian 13 which is testing.
@mYnDstrEAm the dependency on libLLVM is not direct from dolphin-emu, but rather via libglx0 to libglx-mesa0 to libgl1-mesa-dri to libllvm15, based on an install of dolphin-emu into a fresh stable chroot.  Can you run apt-policy on the libglx packages and ensure they are the version from the debian repos?

dolphin-emu is running in the chroot (well, it does until it realizes there's no display).  I suspect there is tomfoolery occuring with the version of libgl1-mesa-dri; the version in bullseye has the mysterious dependency on libllvm11, which explains our issue.  Interestingly, the version in backports does away with that dependency; it becomes a recommendation, and an indirect one at that.  In any case, updating libgl1-mesa-dri to the version in the stable repo should fix the issue; you may need to do a dist-upgrade.

sudo apt policy libglx0 shows Installed: 1.6.0-1 (bookworm/main); and libglx-mesa0 is Installed: 22.3.6-1+deb12u1 with also another version in the Version table from bookworm-backports. When I check in apper it says for both packages that it's from debian stable. libgl1-mesa-dri is at 22.3.6-1 from debian-stable-main. Maybe I also have the backports version and should remove it somehow, I will see if that's possible.

I checked for example with aptitude search '~S ~i ~Abackports' and have basically nothing installed from backports according to that so I don't know how to remove. It seems the right version is selected anyway. I also tried sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri/bookworm for the 3 packages to make sure the right version is selected but it shows the same output for apt policy and still the same llvm error. libgl1-mesa-dri also is 22.3.6-1+deb12u1

Yeah, those versions are all good looking; things installed from backports shouldn't break other packages anyways.

This would be criminal, but maybe someone went and edited the files without telling dpkg.  Try running apt reinstall on those three packages; or running debsums on them.  Other possibilities are that there is some other library hooping in there; try running ldd /usr/games/dolphin-emu, or ldconfig -v |less, and checking for libraries which aren't in /usr/lib.

I think I see the problem now: which dolphin-emu shows /usr/local/bin/dolphin-emu (and I didn't configure this deliberately), not /usr/games/dolphin-emu. I thought the executable in /usr/games was the one I had built from source. So I wonder why dolphin-emu is pointing there and still points there after reinstalling dolphin-emu from the repos. Maybe more people would have this problem when they also had built it from source. I try to find out how to make it point to /usr/games/dolphin-emu.

So, files in /usr/* (with the exception of /usr/local) need to only be managed by apt, and should ideally just be from packages in the distribution.  /usr/local is where locally built versions of things should be put; files there won't be overwritten by dpkg.  It's fairly likeley that the copy of dolphin-emu has been replaced with the offical version; however, the fact that there is a version in /usr/local means that the official version (which probably works!) isn't being run.

Check to see if /usr/local/lib contains many libraries; it could be that there are more files shadowing distribution libraries.  Or maybe deleting (make a backup first, if you want) /usr/local/bin/dolphin-emu will just fix it all.

The problem stems from a bit of a headache of packaging.  libllvm11 is not a direct dependency of dolphin-emu in any version of Debian, and is only an indirect dependency in Debian 11 via mesa's graphics libraries (it's used for Vulkan support).  The version of mesa's graphics packaged in Debian 11 was compiled against and depends on libllvm11; thus, we can conclude that somehow dolphin-emu is using those older libraries.
How remains to be seen from your response; however, from what you said about which dolphin-emu indicating a file in /usr/local/bin (as opposed to /usr/games, where the Debian package would put its files), it seems likley that this whole time you have been trying to run a version of dolphin-emu that partially bundles the mesa drivers, but does not include libllvm.  Thus, when  you try to run it, it seeks for libraries that are not there.
It is also possible that in /usr/local/lib, you have the older mesa drivers for some reason.  In either case, deleting the files in /usr/local/ that are shadowing the Debian-distributed libraries and binaries will solve the problem, allowing the Debian binary to run in the environment it was compiled for.  You can use tools like which, ldd, and ldconfig -v to find which files are doing this shadowing

Okay so I moved the file with sudo mv /usr/local/bin/dolphin-emu /other/dir/dolphin-emu and afterwards dolphin-emu runs again and shows the /usr/games path when running which dolphin. This just shows why building from source shouldn't be required. I asked for a .deb package here. The process to uninstall such /usr/local/lib/ packages and finding problematic ones is not as it should, it can't be right to fix this by moving file. And why did it have the wrong path in the first place? For the runner I'll file a Lutris bug about libavformat.so.60.

Yeah, I'm not certain what happened; in any case, building from source is never required for distribution packages.   It likley had the wrong path because you had previously built from source, and also installed the distribution package.
